# Terraform. Inappropriate value for attribute ... string required

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to split a Terraform list of strings per item with a double quotes for each and as string output format?
I'd like to put this dynamic variable inside the [permissions](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam_custom_role#permissions) argument.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "ext_permissions" {
  type        = list(string)
  default = ["iam.roles.list", "iam.roles.create", "iam.roles.delete"]
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "my-custom-role" {
  role_id     = "myCustomRole"
  title       = "My Custom Role"
  description = "A description"
  permissions = ["iam.serviceAccounts.create","iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy", "${var.ext_permissions}"]
}
```

***Error: Incorrect attribute value type***

> var.ext_permissions is list of string with 2 elements Inappropriate
> value for attribute "permissions": element 9: string required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIS you need list concatenation, like

```
concat(["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]) -> ["a",  "b",  "c",  "d"]
```

or in your case:

```
permissions = concat(["iam.serviceAccounts.create","iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy"], var.ext_permissions)
```